# Saving DialogFragment Drawable image in Saved preferences

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to load image if user has load an image **previously**. I am trying to do this in **onCreate**

Used **DialogFragment** to achieve this since I want to pick image from ***within*** app only.

Here is my **WithNamesFragment Class** :

```
public class WithNamesFragment extends DialogFragment {
    final static ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> imagesWithNames = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        HashMap<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();
        row.put("imageID", R.drawable.aquarius);
        row.put("name", "Aquarius");
        imagesWithNames.add(row);
        row = new HashMap<>();
        row.put("imageID", R.drawable.virgo);
        row.put("name", "Virgo");
        imagesWithNames.add(row);

    }

    @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), imagesWithNames, R.layout.lib_dialog_image,
                new String[]{"name", "imageID"}, new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.image1});
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).setAdapter(adapter,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ((MainActivity) getContext()).OnSelected(WithNamesFragment.this.getClass(), (int) ((HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i)).get("imageID"));
                    }
                }).setCancelable(true).setTitle("PICK YOUR AVATAR").create();
    }
}
```

in **MainActivity** :

```
public void OnSelected(Class<?> clazz, int i) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Class \"" + clazz.getSimpleName() + "\" returns this image with id: " + getResources().getResourceName(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        final TextView toastView = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        toastView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, i, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        Glide.with(this).load(i)
                .crossFade()
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(profimg);
        sp.edit().remove("dp").apply();
        i=this.i;
        sp.edit().putInt("dp",i);
    }
    void show() {
        new WithNamesFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), PICKER_TAG);
    }
```

in **Oncreate** of **MainActivity** :

```
profimg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                show();
            }
        });

 boolean path =sp.contains("dp");

if(path) {
           int value=sp.getInt("dp",i);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            /*Glide.with(this).load(value)
                    .crossFade()
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(profimg);*/
        }
```

This is show method:

```
void show() {
        new WithNamesFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), PICKER_TAG);
    }
```

Earlier I was struggling with Casting error but now I am getting nothing in Toast.

Comment: At which line getting issue?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Wait. Ok That is resolved now. But since this resource I am getting in Withnames fragment and in onSelected I am loading image with glide But look in onCreate method I am just getting resourceID 
Error : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below line :

```
 sp.edit().putInt("dp",i).apply();
```

You have missed the .apply() or .commit()
**Edit Code :** 
initialize SharedPreference first.

```
    Oncreate(){

        final int value = sp.getInt("dp",0);

    if(value>0){
       imageView.setImageResource(value);
    }


}
```

Comment: Casting Exception again it says Java.string.lang cannot be casted to Integer

Comment: At which line getting issue?

Comment: That is resolved but I am getting this now 
Error : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Comment: What to do in onCreate to getResource?

Comment: post your oncreate code. ResourceNotFoundException means that *i* is not in your drawable folder.

Comment: I guess have already added code there associated with this image some were missing adding those look

Comment: I know this i value I am getting in onSelected method but how to get it in onCreate method ?

Comment: In which place you have called OnSelected method in onClick? When you called OnSelected method that time you should pass the proper value of *i* and in onCreate   int value=sp.getInt("dp",i); this code is correct. But first you have to call OnSelected method with correct value.

Comment: I have called show method onclick of imageview this show method has a callback of class WithNamesFragment look I have posted this and after selecting image I am getting resource id in integer "i" look onSelected method parameters and loading this resources id when selected....So Now I want this image to load on app start whatever image I select that should be loaded in onCreate

Comment: i have updated my code. Have you checked your *i* value is correct?

Comment: Yes in onSelected method it's loading image properly wait i'll try your code.....but take a look at this line (int) ((HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i)).get("imageID")

Comment: I did this final int value = sp.getInt("dp",0);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(value), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(value>0)
            {Glide.with(this).load(value)
                    .crossFade()
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(profimg);}

I am getting 0 everytime onstartup first time I will get but next time it should give me the resourceID which I have put in preferences

Comment: Come to Discussion/Chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131149/discussion-between-sameerkhan1406-and-mavya-soni).